# Eliminating "highlight" on button click- XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, button

I have a few buttons on an interface that I've customized the color on. When I mouse over them, they get tinted with that blue that Microsoft uses on things in Windows. It looks great, just not on my color combination (black and gold).

How do I eliminate this highlighting on click behavior? I need to do this for all of my buttons, which inherit from a base style:

```
<Style x:Key="ContentControlElementsStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#F1B82D"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#F1B82D"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following button style.

```
 <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}"  >
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <!--<Trigger Property="Button.IsDefaulted" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>-->
                        <!--<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFBEE6FD"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                        </Trigger>-->
                        <!--<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFC4E5F6"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF2C628B"/>
                        </Trigger>-->
                        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFBCDDEE"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF245A83"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FFADB2B5"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="#FF838383"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I commented the Triggers which cause color change in mouse over and pressed state.

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of:

```
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Image Source="MyAwesomeClickedPicture.png" Height="32" Width="32" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Image Source="MyAwesomePicture.png" Height="32" Width="32" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

But in your case I guess you'd want to set a color not an image like I did

Comment: I think you're on to something... Though I'm not getting rid of the highlighting. I guess it's a manner of which properties are set. Any idea what it might be?

Comment: Are you trying to get rid of the highlighting on Mouse Over? or On Click?

Comment: I'd like to eliminate the highlighting on mouseover, and reverse the colors on click. Sorry if I didn't make that clear before :P