# Change backgorund of button in wpf when it has focus

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I have a button and I want to change the background color of button. but when I set the background property to a color like blue:

```
<Button Width="75" Height="25" Margin="6" Background="Blue"/>
```

and when the button has focus, the color changes in white and my color.

How can I set this white color to another color?

Comment: check buttonstate property .and add trigger based on state

Comment: Try the style given in the following link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20669013/eliminating-highlight-on-button-click-xaml/20681609#20681609

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that your problem is caused by the default `ControlTemplate` for the `Button` control. The colour animations that you describe are defined in this `ControlTemplate` and so you need to provide your own `ControlTemplate` to remove this behaviour:

```
<Button Content="Click Me" Background="Blue">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Button.IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="White" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: your code cause this error: "Cannot find the static member 'ContentProperty' on the type 'Control'"

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite back in proper 'work' mode yet. I forgot to set the essential `TargetType` property and also completely forgot the `Trigger` too. It's all there and working now.

Comment: @Sheridan How can we change the styling of focused button globally? I mean if any button in the entire project gets focused turns blue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33248824/how-to-change-the-styling-of-the-dotted-line-around-focused-button-globally-in-w#33248824

Comment: @WaterfrVilla, you can define a global `Style` in your `App.xaml` file and simply omit the `x:Key` directive... that way, it will apply to all `Button`s in your application. King King has provided an example on your question.

Answer (score 1):

First Solution is

```
 <Style x:Key="BtnStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="gd" Height="120" Width="120" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">        
                                <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>                            
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                                                  
                        <Trigger Property="Button.IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" TargetName="gd"></Setter>                           
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="gd"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
<Button Width="75" Style="{StaticResource BtnStyle }" Content="ok"  Height="25" Background="Blue"/>
```

second solution

```
      <Style x:Key="Button_focusvisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="White">
                        <TextBlock Text="Ok" ></TextBlock>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

      <Button Width="75" FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource Button_focusvisual }" Content="ok"   Height="25" Background="Blue"/>
```

Comment: It has been reported [elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28348044/2670182) that changes since windows 8 has buggered this all up :/