# How to change the styling of the dotted line around focused button globally in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have multiple buttons and images in my WPF applications and would like to make the dotted line around focused buttons and focused images thicker for all of them.

I don't want to do it one by one for each component. Instead I am looking for a way that I can set the styling of the dotted line (dashed line) which indicates what component is focused globally for all of the components.

How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply define an implicit Style targeting `Button` or `Image` or any other focusable Controls, place this Style is such as `App.Resources` or some separate ResourceDictionary:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
   <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle">
       <Setter.Value>
           <Style>
              <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                 <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Black" StrokeDashArray="2"/>
                  </ControlTemplate>
                 </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
           </Style>
       </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```