# How to globally change the styling of the dottet lines around all focusble elements in one place?

Tags: c#, wpf

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33248824/how-to-change-the-styling-of-the-dotted-line-around-focused-button-globally-in-w) I learned how to change the styling of dotted lines around focused button. I would like to apply the same thing on all focus-able elements of the current WPF application (or if not possible current page) in one place ( not doing separately for focus-able buttons, textboxes etc)

PS. Preferably in code behind

Comment: `Preferably in code behind` - Not really.

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Define this Style in your App.Xaml .

```
<Application.Resources>
   <Style x:Key="StyleFocusDefault" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
      <Setter Property="Template">
       <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
              <Grid>
                <Rectangle StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Black" StrokeDashArray="2"/>
              </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
   </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

And then you can apply like : `< ... FocusVisualStyle="{DynamicResource StyleFocusDefault}" .../>`

This will change FocusVisualStyle for all Controls who have FocusVisualStyle property. You can further experiment with this appaorach for various controls.