# Show focused element on loaded control in WPF

Tags: wpf, focus, highlight

How do I highlight the focused element in my view after it has been loaded? I know it's focused because if I press Enter or navigate with the keyboard it behaves as expected, and if if I navigate back to the first element it gets correctly highlighted. I'd just like to make it clear to the user which element is selected after the view has been loaded. This happens with either buttons or checkboxes.

Comment: You can use a style to set the template and a trigger in that to change background. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949742/change-backgorund-of-button-in-wpf-when-it-has-focus

Comment: Is it any different from             
`<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisualStyleBtn}" />`
? 
It works fine when navigating through elements but it doesnt apply to the focused element after it has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The focussed style will be applied if the control is the focussed element. A focused element is different to a default element which may allow an action to be performed if enter is pressed.

Setting focus needs to be done explicitly, in the example it is done be the following line

```
FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=Button}"
```

This sets the focus on the button, running this you should see the button is highlighted. Remove the above line and the button will not be highlighted.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=Button}"
        mc:Ignorable="d"        
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button IsDefault="False"
                Width="150"
                Height="30"
                Name="Button"
                Content="Button"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: The code above didn't solve my problem, although I was able to shed a bit more light into the matter.

Apparently the wanted behaviour is triggered if I interact with the UI with the keyboard.
Example: I press the enter key  on a button and an new window opens up. Said window has a list of checkboxes and the first one is visibly highlighted.

If I press the same button with MouseLeft, the same window will open up but no highlighting is visible on the checkbox.

I assume there's some hidden behaviour tied to the KeyBoardFocus event, is there any way to force it?

Comment: I checked and both Logical and Keyboard Focus are set on the button, nevertheless the behaviour is consistently different depending on how I trigger the appeareance of the UserControl

Comment: If you are still struggling with this, add a simple example of what you are trying to within your question and it will help determine what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

wow I totally forgot about asking about this. At the end I had to remove the FocusVisualStyle property set on my style and write a simple trigger on the IsFocused event.That took care of my issue.